# Adjectives as determinatives

Tags: determiners

Consider the following sentences, which could have appeared as such in academic texts:

> Obiges Zitat ist aufschlussreich.
>   Genanntes Beispiel hilft uns weiter.
>   Besagte Theorie wurde schon längst widerlegt.

These sentences turn ungrammatical as soon as we remove "obiges", "genanntes" or "besagtes". Furthermore, the noun phrases are definite (in contrast to, say "honey"). This leads to the conclusion that the leading words of the sentences ain't adjectives but determiners.

I believe it is a curious feature that German has a set of determiners (thus, grammatical words) that are derived from adjectives and only occur in literal and formal language. Something similar is the case for 'aforesaid' in English, compare [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aforesaid).

1. Is there academic work on this?
2. How did these forms evolve?

PS:
I just noticed to following description of the tag 'article' : "An article is a word that precedes a noun and determines its gender." It should be known that this is nonsense.

Comment: The tag wikis are, um, wikis.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow your logic, starting with the sentences becoming ungrammatical by removing the lead words. Can you explain that? Also, "obig" is the only true lead adjective whereas "genannt" and "besagt" are technically participles acting as adjectives, so your examples seem to be a mix of types for what you seem to be asking. Regardless, they are functioning as if an indefinite article preceded them and don't determine the nouns' genders themselves. Can you please clarify a little further what you're asking? Maybe I'm missing something here. :)

Comment: Actually, at least _Genanntes Beispiel hilft uns weiter_ is ungrammatical to me, too. I guess it is just that some people drop _das_ out of parsimony.

Comment: Frankly speaking, those sentences don't seem as they could have appeared in academic text but rather headlines. In an academic text there definitely would be a definite article preceding them. "Das obige Zitat" "Das genannte Beispiel" "Die besagte Theorie". And in a headtitle, you can do this with every adjective.

Comment: Da Überschriften das erste eines Artikels sind und vorher/darüber noch nichts gesagt oder genannt worden ist kann die Formulierung gerade nicht in Überschriften auftauchen. `Das, jenes, dieses` kann aber anstelle von `obiges, genanntes, besagtes` stehen.

Comment: @userunknown Ich denke, das war an mich gerichtet?! Ich habe nicht gesagt, dass die 3 Beispiel Titel sind. Ich hab nur gesagt, dass das Muster typisch für Titel sind und man eben solches mit jedem Adjektiv machen kann. Und ich weiß nicht, woher die Beispiele stammen, aber die klingen absolut nicht wie Teil einer akademischen Arbeit.

Comment: Statt in einer akademischen Arbeit würde ich besagte Formulierungen eher in Beamten- oder Juristendeutsch vermuten.

Comment: @Em1: Ja, ich vergaß Dich zu adressieren. Heißt `but rather headlines` nicht `sondern eher Überschriften`? Überschriften geht aber kein anderer Satz vorraus, auf die sich ein `besagte Theorie` beziehen kann, außer, wie so oft, es handelt sich um ein Dadagedicht.

Comment: @userunknown Lies meinen Kommentar und VERSTEH ihn. Und lies ihn nochmal, wenn du es nicht verstehst. Danke.

Comment: @Em1: Ich versteh 's nicht. :) Da hilft aber auch BRÜLLEN nicht.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are missing out on one aspect of German grammar as a whole. Nouns do NOT always need a determiner.

- Rotwein passt nicht gut zu Fisch.

So we have 3 possible arrangements:

- definite determiner - adjective (or other descibing stuff) - noun
- indefinite det. - adjective - noun
- empty - adjective - noun

That is why there are 3 declension tables for German adjectives. And it doesn't matter which adjective we are talking about. It works with lexical adjectives as well as with derivatives. So what you found are 100% rule compliant examples. Here are 2 more examples:

- Roter Wein passt gut zu rotem Fleisch.
- Großer Hund wird von mutig agierendem Mann von frisch gebauter Autobahn getragen.

The second example does sound like a headline and an ugly one at that. But it is correct anyway and it uses the whole variety of what is possible.